# PL/SQL Execute immediate create table and insert data into it

Tags: plsql, execute

Let's have a look on my source code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MAKE_COPY_OF_CLASSROOMS AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS

TYPE classrooms_table_type IS TABLE OF classrooms%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
classrooms_backup classrooms_table_type;

CURSOR classrooms_cursor IS
SELECT *
FROM classrooms
WHERE year = 1
ORDER BY name;

v_rowcnt PLS_INTEGER := 0;

BEGIN
    OPEN classrooms_cursor;
        FETCH classrooms_cursor
         BULK COLLECT INTO classrooms_backup;
    CLOSE classrooms_cursor;    

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE classrooms_copy AS (SELECT * FROM classrooms WHERE 1 = 2)';
--COPY ALL STORED DATA FROM classrooms_backup TO classrooms_copy

END MAKE_COPY_OF_classrooms;
```

I'm stucked for hours on trying to insert data from "classrooms_backup" into the table "classrooms_copy", which is created by EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command. It's necessary to create table "classrooms_copy" via EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command. I tried to create another EXECUTE command with for loop in it:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'FOR i IN classrooms_backup.FIRST..classrooms_backup.LAST LOOP
  INSERT INTO classrooms_copy(id,room_id,year,name) 
  VALUES(classrooms_backup(i).id,classrooms_backup(i).room_id,classrooms_backup(i).year,classrooms_backup(i).name);
  END LOOP;';
```

But it's road to the hell. I'm retrieving an invalid SQL statement error.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for much PL/SQL here.  Also, try to avoid the keyword `CURSOR` - there's almost always a better way to do it.

```
create or replace procedure make_copy_of_classrooms authid current_user as
begin
    execute immediate '
        create table classrooms_copy as
        select *
        from classrooms
        where year = 1
        order by name
    ';
end make_copy_of_classrooms;
/
```

Comment: I'm forced to create a temporary object (classroom_backup), print the content of the classroom_backup to the command line and after that, I have to create the table classrooms_copy by EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and fill that table with data stored in the classroom_backup...

Comment: Finally I did it. @Jon your solution looks better and easier, but it wouldn't correspond to my homework instructions.